# Docker container access to local DNS

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, dns, vmware-workstation

Due to company restrictions I'm having to run docker inside a VMware Workstation VM with Ubuntu installed from a Windows host.

From the Ubuntu terminal I'm able to ping by domain to both, Internet servers and servers from the local network. When I run a docker container I can't resolve any domain even though I can ping to both IPs.

```
docker run -t mycontainer
```

If I run the docker container setting the local DNS using the --dns LOCALDNS option, I'm only able to resolve domains servers on Internet but not from the local network. I'm now running the containers like this:

```
docker run --dns XX.XX.1.1 -t mycontainer
```

Is there a way to configure the docker network so that the containers can resolve local AND Internet servers?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe `--network=host` ?

Comment: It didn't had any effect

Comment: There's an open issue with vpnkit (used by docker) that may apply to you: https://github.com/moby/vpnkit/issues/221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out a solution to the problem. Additionally to the --dns option I had to add the --dns-search option with the domain name. The command I'm using is as follows:

```
docker run --dns XX.XX.1.1 --dns-search companydomain -t mycontainer
```